# GRAPH API retuning empty JSON for albums or photos query (with all needed permissions enabled)

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, photo

I am trying to get user album by using GRAPH API with function

```
facebook.request(contact.getFacebook_id()+"/albums")
```

but in return i get only string with no albums :

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

It only happens to certain users IDs. For example there is no problem in quering

```
facebook.request(contact.getFacebook_id())

facebook.request(contact.getFacebook_id()+"/picture");
```

It happens only for quering albums and their pictures.
I have permissions: user_photos and friend_photos

`contact.getFacebook_id()` is for getting user ID (it is not null for, I have checked it)

Comment: did you try to give the formed url in the browser and checked whether there are any photos of the particular user or not?

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133014/facebook-album-and-photos-unaccessible-with-all-needed-permission-graph-api

Comment: I started bounty in another question. Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133014/facebook-album-and-photos-unaccessible-with-all-needed-permission-graph-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some reasearch it is not a bug. Facebook has another privacy settings for third party applications and its own application, due to that i was missled to conclusion that action mention in question is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to give the permissions `user_photo_video_tags` for your photos and for friends photos you need to also give the permission `friends_photo_video_tags`

Still if you have any problem then please check the `access_token` whether its retrieved properly or not.

Comment: yup I added those and problem persists. Now I have
friends_about_me, friends_photo_video_tags, friends_photos, user_photos.

Token seems to be right it works for other users IDs.

Comment: did you check in the by giving the url in the browser whether there are photos present in that particular user's profile or not?