# Facebook Album and Photos unaccessible with all needed permission (GRAPH API)

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, permissions

In my android application I download album list of specified friend of user.

I've got permission as follows:friends_about_me, friends_photo_video_tags, friends_photos, user_photos.

For some friends it works perfectly and I am able to download full list and all photos. But for some it returns empty array. Is this a case of friend privacy policy or this is FB bug?

If i try to view this friend albums via FB page or via FB android app it works fine.

Edit: I did get user album id from URL from FB page and paste it to GRAPH API explorer and it returned false to me.

Question is: what to do to get album list and album photos?

Comment: Hi! I'm also trying to achieve something similar to what you acomplished - download friends albums. I'm a begginer with android, could you share some code or directions? thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Privacy Settings

(Currently) under `Account > Privacy settings > Apps and Websites "Edit your settings"`, there is a way for users to set what information your app can access through their friends, regardless of what permissions their friends grant to the app.

[image: Info accessible through your friends]

If the person you are trying to see albums from has unchecked "My Photos", then they have to grant the app permission directly (described below). By default it is checked, and your app can access the user's photos. If the box is unchecked, then there is no way for your app to get their photos without them adding your app and giving you access.

With the [changes](https://www.facebook.com/about/details/) that are being rolled out to facebook's privacy settings, these settings are likely to be moved, but hopefully the functionality will still be around.

**Update** 8/30 - My facebook account was just enabled with the changes referred to above. The dialog is the same, just under a different label: `Account > Privacy Settings > Apps and Websites > How people bring your info to apps they use "Edit settings"`. Some of the text was updated and some options are slightly different, but otherwise the settings are the same.

#### Testing

Configure two accounts like so:

Account 1:

1. Two groups for friends, one of which is called "restricted"
2. Photo albums (except for 'Profile pics') set so that 'Friends only; except Restricted group' can see them. Profile pics is set to friends only.
3. "My photos" unchecked in "Info accessible through friends"
4. Very liberal permissions to app (`friends_about_me, friends_photo_video_tags, friends_photos, user_photos` among others)

Account 2:

1. Friends with account 1
2. Granted same permissions to app

By toggling privacy controls (checking/unchecking the checkbox in question, granting/revoking privileges for the app on Account 1, and adding/removing Account 2 to the "Restricted" group) on Account 1 and trying to access that account's photo albums, you will find that with the `My Photos` checkbox in account 1:

- Checked

  - Any app with the `friends_photos` permission used by Account 2 can see any photos visible to Account 2
- Unchecked

  - Apps used by friends of Account 1 cannot access any photos, *unless...*
  - **UNLESS** Account 1 has added  your app and granted the `user_photos` permission. In this case the app has access to any albums visible to Account 2.

So the only way Account 2 can access Account 1's albums (`/<userid>/albums`) with the "My photos" box unchecked is when Account 2 is *not* in the "restricted" group **and** Account 1 has the app enabled with the `user_photos` permission. When Account 2 *is* restricted, the only album it can see is (as expected) the 'Profile pictures' one. When Account 1 either deletes the app or enables it without granting the `user_photos` permissions, the `/albums` connection returns an empty array.

So while it may seem like an error that you get an empty array back, it's actually completely deterministic and expected behavior. On top of that it's good from a user privacy standpoint that Facebook gives users control over this setting.

### So how do you get their photos?

You don't. Or, you shouldn't, anyway. If they've taken the time to disable access to their photos through their friends, you should respect their privacy.

That said, it is technically still *possible* to log in to facebook.com as one of their friends and see the photos they've shared with their friends but not with their friends' apps. In theory you could write a web crawler that would automatically perform such a task, although it is against facebooks [terms of service](http://www.facebook.com/terms.php) and you would be a Bad Person for doing so:

> [3.2] You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our permission.

Comment: That is great answer! Thank you. Sadly privacy settings distinguish application and user.

Comment: I think it's important and good to distinguish between apps and users, since apps, being computer programs, can take your photos or other data and do a lot more with them than a user could. I'm thinking data harvesting and the like- the same "limitation" applies to friend lists, which are not generally accessible in any API, but are still visible on Facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

u should run a test, 
create 2 facebook test profiles (or use friends account)
make one private and the other public and see the results

i would be willing to bet it is the privacy settings

if it works regardless of the privacy settings then maybe your making to many request simultaneously and getting getting dropped because of it.

Comment: I will try. 

There are two requests. First: /me/friends and after that /friend_id/albums and second one returns empty result. It works for most people, so it is not a case of count of request.

Comment: Graph API doesn't drop requests because you make too many requests; I have an app that made hundreds of thousands of requests with no problem. I'd put my money on privacy settings.